# Style TextView as material-style Spinner on API level 19

Tags: android, textview, styles, android-appcompat

I'm trying to style a `TextView` like a spinner in my app, so that it looks like a spinner but does allow me to easily show a custom dialog for editing the value.

I use the following in my layout XML:

```
<TextView
    style="?android/spinnerStyle"
    ...
/>
```

All works as expected on an Android 5 emulator. My `TextView` and other `Spinner`s look alike. They display a litte down-arrow on the right:

[image: The material spinner arrow]

However, when I run the same code on an Android 4.4 emulator, the `Spinner`s still look like above (because I'm using the Support Library in the most recent version), but the `TextView` looks like an Android 4.4 spinner:

[image: Old non-material spinner style]

This results in an inconsistent look in my Activity. I notice that `Spinner` is one of the controls the style of which is handled by the support library for Android versions older than 5.

The question I have is: Is there a way to tell the `TextView` to use the AppCompat spinner style as well? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you using support library?

Comment: @PankajKumar Yes. Sorry for not making this clearer in the question, I'm going to edit.

Comment: Would be highly interesting to hear why this question was downvoted...

Comment: Hey that was not me who downvoted :) and I have no reason to do that

Comment: I didn't mean to say it was you - still would be interesting to know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I accidentially found the styles myself. The following provides the layout as desired:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]
You can use this styling after download a icon of lower triangle and adding it as an asset to your drawables, U can adjust margin as per your requirements in the relative layout and Textview.

You can them use onClickListeners to add actions like displaying a custom edit dialog or anything

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_sort_down"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, this is not quite what I want. See my own answer.